# Django query to sort alphanumeric values

Tags: django

I have a column `desc` in which data like

```
A1, A0, A9, A11, B3, B11
```

need to sort this data as

```
A0, A1, A9, A11, B3, B11
```

but `MyModel.objects.all().order_by('desc')` query returns

```
A0, A1, A11, A9, B11, B3
```

What can I do.

Note: `desc` is CharField.

Answer (score 0):

You can use queryset's [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method:

```
# since first letter is not a number you can use substring
MyModel.objects.all().extra({
   'unsigned_desc': "CAST(substring(desc, 2) AS UNSIGNED)"
}).order_by('unsigned_desc')
```